Get caller information in C# for multiple calls on same line
On C# you can get some information about the caller of a method via the [Caller*] attributes. You can get the member name, file path and line number of the caller. But what happens when the method is called multiple times on the same line? Can the calls be differentiated?
For example:
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

static void LogCaller(
    string message,
    [CallerFilePath] string callerFilePath = "",
    [CallerMemberName] string callerName = "",
    [CallerLineNumber] int callerLine = 0
) {
    Console.WriteLine($"{message} [{callerFilePath}, {callerLine}, {callerName}]");
}

LogCaller("Hello call 1");

LogCaller("Hello call 2");

LogCaller("Hello call 3"); LogCaller("Hello call 4");

Gives the following output:
Hello call 1 [/home/devel/tst/Program.cs, 12, <Main>$]
Hello call 2 [/home/devel/tst/Program.cs, 14, <Main>$]
Hello call 3 [/home/devel/tst/Program.cs, 16, <Main>$]
Hello call 4 [/home/devel/tst/Program.cs, 16, <Main>$]

Where 'call 3' and 'call 4' can't be differentiated. Can it be done?
Regards.

Not sure what you mean by "differentiated"? You are getting 2 separate output lines (Hello call 3 & Hello call 4) which both reference the input line (16). The 2 separate output lines are not differentiation enough?

Well, the message argument is just for this example. The real method could be without args, for example.

There is a proposal to add this functionality which is still open.
In the meantime you can make use of CallerArgumentExpression introduced with C#10/.NET 6 (good intro) if you want to differentiate by the the argument expression that it used to invoke the method and not only the value of this expression (the argument itself):
void LogCaller(
    string message,
    [CallerLineNumber] int callerLine = 0,
    [CallerArgumentExpression(nameof(message))] string messageExpression = ""
) {
    Console.WriteLine($"[Line:{callerLine}, Expression: __{messageExpression}__ with value: {message}]");
}


var message3 = "Same message";
var message4 = "Same message";
LogCaller(message3); LogCaller(message4); // works for you
LogCaller("Same message"); LogCaller("Same message"); // won't work for you

Output:
[Line:6, Expression: __message3__ with value: Same message]
[Line:6, Expression: __message4__ with value: Same message]
[Line:7, Expression: __"Same message"__ with value: Same message]
[Line:7, Expression: __"Same message"__ with value: Same message]


CallerArgumentExpression won't manage all the cases I want to control, but as this is for an 'experimental toy' project, I can work with it by now. If I finally need full control maybe I'll have to try something using source generators to get the information I need.

@Pelko I remember seeing something about character number in a Nick Chapsas video a while back about Interceptors - it was source-generator related (as is the attribute I proposed here). Would be interested what the non-lazy solution to your problem would be.
